# Structuring a RESTful API with Node/JS that serves multiple languages

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express

This is not a question I've really seen answered on SO.  Most of the tutorials on building RESTful API's using node/express focus on a single technology stack.  What my team is having trouble with is building a single Node API that serves multiple stacks, specifically both Angular and Scala but with perhaps more to come later.

In most of the examples I've seen with Angular (for instance), the routing code that Angular uses to set up its MVC goes right into the "app.js" which it seems would not then scale at all to other platforms.  My suspicion is that the "trick" is to break the routing out into a separate file in order to set up multiple routing schema using route separation.  And then set up routes that go `/angular/foo` or `/scala/bar`, etc., on top of which these platforms can be built.

I'm not looking for a "best" way, I'm looking for specific high-level examples of how this problem can be solved, with direct correlation to the node/express stack at the base of the architecture.

Comment: I don't understand why each language needs a different stack. Why can you not use JSON (which most languages have support for) and work out the differences on the client side?

Comment: Are you saying angular and scala are consumers of the api? Or you want node to sit in between the browser and scala?

Comment: Angular and Scala are consumers of the API.  If that's really unclear from what I wrote do you have suggestions for an edit?

Comment: @DanPantry I'm not saying each language needs a different stack, see my response to Ryan, above.  The second part of what you say...maybe that's the solution.  But to use Angular, for instance, doesn't Angular have to be in on the routing game?  So adding all of the controllers and paths, etc, that ends up going into node app itself, right?

Comment: Angular applications are typically SPAs. They don't change page (At least not in the traditional page-per-request sense), and all routing is handled on the client side. They just  consume RESTful APIs in the background. the RESTful API typically is a JSON, language independent, endpoint. Angular apps are then served from a static file server.. this *can* be node but could also be nginx. (TLDR, no, generally speaking the only thing that angular uses in node are the API end points)

Comment: Ah...very good point! Not sure why that didn't occur to me.  Of course, a separate file server for each.  Please submit that answer for points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your comments, it appears that there was a bit of confusion and you were trying to fudge Scala and Angular together in an app, and you wanted to have separate endpoints for each one to serve for routing.

Generally speaking, Angular applications are typically SPAs. They don't change page (At least not in the traditional page-per-request sense), and all routing is handled on the client side. They just consume RESTful APIs in the background. The RESTful API typically is a JSON, language independent, endpoint. Angular apps are then served from a static file server.. this can be node but could also be Nginx (or similar).

Now, some angular applications will have all of the routes for their endpoints rewritten to their app.js from the server side. In other words, you may see an Angular application redirect all requests to it's app.js so the client side can handle the routing. This is useful in case someone on an Angular application refreshes the page for example. This is only necessary however if you're using the HTML5 history API - hashbangs don't need this rewriting.

Scala and Angular don't need to have different endpoints for data - only for their file serving. The REST endpoints could be exactly the same as long as they output a format both languages understand (typically JSON).

Comment: Well...more accurately we were thinking Node had to both serve the pages and the API, but "fudge" works too ;-)  Thanks Dan.

Comment: Oh, that's not a fudge at all to serve pages AND API from the same server (You wouldn't want to in a very large production environment obviously)! But I've never seen scala/node interop. Could you explain how you would imagine that work in more detail? It might be my answer is not the best suited.

Comment: For Scala I have no idea.  But for Angular it seemed I need the core app.js that serves the API to also help with the controller set up, etc.  And if this is something that can't be done in a large production environment then our goose is cooked on that solution anyway.

Comment: You can run multiple instances of node to achieve using the cluster module and or child processes, so it's not impossible. I hasten to remind you that premature optimization is the root of all evil and node is really impressively fast. I wasn't saying you would never ever do it (because you can), but if you're doing an SPA and an API you typically have a high performance static file server (nginx) on one box and you have node serving your API on another box.

Comment: One of our developers built a "multiple instances of Node" solution and looks like we're going in that direction.  Thanks Dan!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you would want two different APIs for different stacks. Why aren't you able to use one API for both Angular and Scala?

But if you want to split up your API into multiple files, I suggest to use `express.Router`: http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#router

Comment: I *don't* want two different API's.  I want one API that serves both stacks.  Maybe I need to re-word the question...